# Failed to find provider info for pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-search

I have a search page called "SearchItem" on which I've implemented the searchDialog. When I try to search between suggestions, Android keeps on complaining saying:

> Failed to find provider info for pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider

My *AndroidManifest.xml* is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchItem"
            android:label="Cerca il problema"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


            <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchBackend" />

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SearchBackend"
            android:label="Cerca il problema">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name ="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>

        <provider android:name="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa.SolutionProvider"
            android:authorities="pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa"
            android:exported="true">
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".VisualizeItem"
            android:label="Visualizza le soluzioni presenti"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        </activity>
    </application>
```

and the *SolutionProvider* package is:

```
pioperation.tregliapi.computercomesifa;
```

I don't know where I'm wrong but I can't really understand...

Comment: Please make sure that the all places where **authorities** are defined have the **same value**.

Comment: Where should be edited the authorities? I have used them just in the AndroidManifest.xml!!!!

Comment: Please have a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) - there is a least one XML file which contains the `android:contentAuthority` attribute named *syncadapter.xml* in the guide.

Comment: I don't use at all the sync adapter....I'm trying to create a custom SuggestionProvider.....I've read this:          [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html) that is the actual developer guide and it never talks about that service....

Comment: My fault. Somehow I got you completely wrong. Please ignore what I wrote.

Comment: No one can help me out?

Comment: I assume you created a `ContentProvider` for the `SuggestionProvider`. Can you please post the configuration of the `ContentProvider`. It should at least contain a string for the `AUTHORITY` to build an `Uri` from.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much JDD!!!!